# What does the space in between selectors mean?

Tags: css, syntax

I recently encountered this syntax which is new to me. I tried to do some experiments to see what it actually does but can't say for sure, so I need help. This is the code in css:

```
.animation-element.slide-left.testimonial .content {
  some styling statements;
}
```

Is there a difference between putting a space in-between the selectors and not doing it? And if that's the case, what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a space and not a space is like this:

```
<div class="animation-element slide-left testimonial">
    <div class="content">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

So `.animation-element.slide-left.testimonal` is all **one element** with multiple classes. Then the `.content` after that is getting a descendant element of the element before that.

Comment: You have a full doc on the CSS selectors here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Maybe I'm being silly but that doesn't state elements with multiple classes? Although overall that is a really helpful sheet :) @Zahori

Comment: Yes, I know but it explain which seletor do ;)

Comment: "is getting a child element" — Not necessarily a child. **Any** descendant. The child combinator is `>`.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, any child/descendant element. I think it might be my use of language that meant one thing to me but another to someone else :) Will change thanks @Quentin

Comment: Thanks everyone. I didn't know how to formulate the question, otherwise I think I would have found all your suggested links.  :/